# Why icons are showing as � in production?

Tags: css, material-design, production-environment, google-fonts

I'm using font-family:'Material Design Iconic' for some icons in the grails project. It's working perfectly in dev environment but some of the icons are showing as '�?�' in production for 'class="site-menu-icon icon md-markunread-mailbox"'. I have cleaned the project and then created the war file. I don't have any idea what's the root cause behind this? Here is the code used to get the icon:
[image]

Can anybody help me with this?

```
.md-markunread-mailbox:before {
    content: '�?�';
}
```

While debugging I got the above CSS....
Edit:- Adding the screenshot of css file getting in production

Comment: Are there any warnings/errors in console related to css/fonts ?

Comment: content-type is text/html

Comment: yes i have warnings listed below : chs-fc74abd7c4473d92bcc6b44a171b4aba.js:10153 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.    
 But I'm getting this in dev environment also...there icons are working fine...

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask what's the content-type and encoding?

Answer (score -1):

can you try this?

```
.md-markunread-mailbox::before {content: "face";}
```

or you could use unicode "\e84d"

P.S: is an example

Comment: Changing the content value to some other value is working but I'm using material-design.css file for this icon. I won't be able to change the CSS.  It is a predefined CSS which is defined by the  material-design.css file.